# File not launching in Client Side Java (Server/Client) App no Web

Tags: java, sockets, oop, client-server, server

Problem: My File not Launching which is requested from sever.

Okay I have written a server/client application but the problem is when i request for a file from the server it transfer over to the client but what I have notice is that I need to manually refresh the directory to get the file to be in the path or directory. So by saying that, I feel that this is why my code when request the file it doesn't launch.

My approach launching the file from the client after it had just been requested.

Here is my code below:

```
public static void receiveFile(String fileName) {
    try {
        int bytesRead;
        InputStream in = sock.getInputStream();

        DataInputStream clientData = new DataInputStream(in);

        fileName = clientData.readUTF();
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream((fileName));//need to state a repository
        long size = clientData.readLong();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (size > 0 && (bytesRead = clientData.read(buffer, 0, (int) Math.min(buffer.length, size))) != -1) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            size -= bytesRead;
        }

        output.close();
        in.close();
        File file = new File(fileName);
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);

        //System.out.println("File "+fileName+" received from Server.");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        //Logger.getLogger(CLIENTConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Please can you look are tell me what you think I am doing wrong?
Server code:

Comment: well maybe your `receiveFile` function is throwing an exception, and as you are silently swallowing it, you will never know.

Comment: Plz paste the client side code also..

Comment: Paste  you server side code as well

Comment: Can I ask could it be because I am not writing the File to specific folder for when I wrote just the desktop code to launch a file from the root of the project it didn't but when I add the file to resources directory it did. Am wondering if I were to write the file from the stream to a specified folder resources an try to launch it what would happen am coming with the sever code

Comment: Okay it was my bad I notice the file that was passing was only 0 bytes I sought that out. Also I am having another prob where it is not launching the pdf app but it loads it in the pdf app so say I open some other file you will see the file i requested inside the pdf app but i need it to be invoke after transfer. Remember I solve the the part to get to send over and load in a respective file formatted app. the app file just wont launch

Comment: The answer is to use Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + file); okay I solve it

Answer (score 0):

Try flush the stream before close.

```
output.flush();
output.close();
```

Comment: Excuse me.. which flush you are talking about.. If you are closing the stream, then there is no need of flushing

Comment: A flush is performed when `close` is called

Answer (score 0):

I solve it my self the answer is to use the code below:

replace:    Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);

with:   Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + file);